# Why i get <__main__.Node object at 0x000001EF886AB2E0> when i output Node's name?

Tags: python

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def search1(root, value):
    if root is None or root.val == value:
        return root

    if root.val > value:
        return search1(root.left, value)

    if root.val < value:
        return search1(root.right, value)

def search2(root, value):
    while root != None and root.val != value:
        if root.val > value:
            root = root.left
        elif root.val < value:
            root = root.right
            return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Node(15)
    b = Node(6)
    c = Node(18)
    d = Node(4)
    e = Node(8)
    f = Node(17)
    g = Node(20)
    h = Node(13)
    i = Node(9)
    a.left = b
    a.right = c
    b.left = d
    b.right = e
    c.left = f
    c.right = g
    e.right = h
    h.left = i

    print(search1(a, 13))
    print(search2(a, 13))
```

output: `<__main__.Node object at 0x000001EF886AB2E0>`

How can I convert the address of this Node() to the name of Node()?

Comment: What do you mean by the "name of node"? You printed a `Node` object, that is the default string representation of an object inherited from `object.__repr__`

Comment: Your node doesn't even have a name. There is val, left and right, but no name.

Answer (score 2):

Either simply by

a) Accessing the attribute on print

```
print(search1(a, 13).val)
print(search2(a, 13).val)
```

or b) by overwriting the `__str__` or `__repr__` method within your `Node` class. The former is used for more *human readable output*  (e.g., in a GUI) while the latter is more for a *technical/development related output*.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node: ' + str(self.val)
```

`__str__` is used by the builtin `print` function or `str` function. If it is not defined, they fall back to `__repr__`. `__repr__` is also used by the python command line and used by the builtin `repr` function.

Output of `print`:

```
15
```

Output in Python CLI:

```
$ python3
from <your-module-name-here> import Node
a = Node(15)
>>> print(a)
15
>>> a
Node: 15
```